# Actual Ads showing instead of Test Ads in Admob

Tags: android

I a seeing actual ads instead of test ads in my app. Check out the image and code.[image]

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    //AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)        // All emulators
            .addTestDevice("32F40C185F4A9214").addTestDevice("31B340D6693D6C01").addTestDevice("759E79391A5A27C3")
            .addTestDevice("aa6705960ab37b0d")
            .build();
    mAdView.loadAd(request);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure out of this 4 device id's there is one valid id of your device?

please check in your logs, Admob prints your device id in it. Put the same device id in addTestDevice();

Answer (score 1):

**Your Device Id might be wrong.**

Add test deviceId like this, so you don't need to replace it when device change.

```
.addTestDevice(getDeviceId(context))
```

Code for getDeviceId() and md5()

```
public static String getDeviceId(Context context)
{
    String android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    String deviceId = md5(android_id).toUpperCase();
    //return deviceId;
    return "0";
}

public static final String md5(final String s) {
    try {
        // Create MD5 Hash
        MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest
                .getInstance("MD5");
        digest.update(s.getBytes());
        byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();

        // Create Hex String
        StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < messageDigest.length; i++) {
            String h = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]);
            while (h.length() < 2)
                h = "0" + h;
            hexString.append(h);
        }
        return hexString.toString();

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: @MsYvette i have offesnced one person's post, so it might be revenge :)

Comment: @MsYvette , not only this post, but 3-4 other posts also .

Comment: That user is suspended, i have posted question on meta related to this event http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272161/how-can-i-flag-illegal-reputation-farming

Comment: @MsYvette actualy both person are posting questions and giving answer to each other, so i have mentioned it in comment and both get suspended

Answer (score 0):

from the [androidcookbook admob tutorial](https://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=724&recipeFrom=ViewTOC)

> When integrating AdMob ads into your application it is recommended to use test mode. In test mode test, ads are always returned. Test mode is enabled on a per-device basis. To enable test mode for a device, first request an ad, then look in LogCat for a line like the following:
>
> To get test ads on the emulator use AdManager.setTestDevices...
>
> Once you have the device ID you can enable test mode by calling in your main activity AdManager.setTestDevices:
>
> AdManager.setTestDevices( new String[] { AdManager.TEST_EMULATOR, "E83D20734F72FB3108F104ABC0FFC738", //Phone ID
> } );

Comparing the two screenshots, it's looks to me that your program is correctly configured for test mode.